# Php update record, repeat region cron job

Tags: php, mysql, cron

This has been a problem for me for a while, but I honestly have NO clue how to write this script. Essentially, what I want to do is have a cron job that will be called daily and then update all variables under the "Age" field in my database. I also have a date of birth while helps change this variable at the moment, (Subtracting todays age with the DOB). Ive looked up a lot for cron jobs and I understand that you have one file which has all the code in it to do one job.

What I THINK I should do is create a repeat region that just updates every record as it is pulled from the server, but other people have been telling me differently. I'm new in programming and this Cron Job thing has REALLY been confusing me on what I'm doing. If I could have a good explanation, or even someone help me write this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Basically, a cron job is just the automation of a script (php or whatever language).
So first, just do the php script that will update your database without thinking about the cron. Then when your php script will work as expected.
Add this script to the crontab in order to be executed one time a day.
You have many explanation on internet for how to add a job in a crontab.

Comment: @olibiaz thank you, that did help with explaining it and what I needed. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cron is just timesheet for periodical jobs. So you should write your script with code wich will update needed data. For example this script will be updater.php. Then you should add to crontab string like this (this script will be repeating every day in 12 p.m.)

```
 0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php path/to/updater.php &> /dev/null
```

If you need help for writing updater.php you should add some info about your schema